# How get the value send to netcat?

Tags: shell, http, netcat

for example I open a port in nc

```
nc -l -p 8080 -q 1
```

And I send to my netcat some http requets, how can I read that value or save in a var to manipulate?
I try to do this

```
echo 'API IN http://localhost:8080'
while true; do
 echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" $? | nc -l  -p 8080 -q 1
done
```

Comment: What do you expect `$?` to mean or do in this context? It's going to be set by `true`, so the value can never be anything except 0.

Comment: ...in general, netcat is not the tool I would recommend for your current job. `socat` is a lot more flexible, in particular.

Comment: For example I open my nc, nc -lp 8080, and in another terminal i sen nc 0.0.0.0 8080, then I send some value, instead of print that value, how can I save in a var?

Comment: (I doing just for study case, not production tools)

Comment: Capturing stdout from a command into a variable is `variable=$(yourcommand)`, so `value=$(nc -l -p 8080 -q 1)`; same for netcat as for anything else.

Comment: ...that said, for more interactive purposes, you might want to invoke `nc` in a `coproc`.

Comment: thanks, I will try with coproc